# Oracle SQL - Display rows as columns - Many to Many Relationship

Tags: sql, database, oracle, data-modeling, bi-publisher

Good day! I need some guidance if I want to do is actually possible in Oracle SQL.

I have a table like this:

| ID | Name | Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 999 | Abby | 1 |
| 999 | Betty | 1 |
| 999 | Cass | 2 |
| 999 | Diane | 2 |
| 999 | Elly | 2 |
| 999 | Faye | 3 |
| 999 | Greg | 4 |
| 999 | Honey | 4 |
| 999 | Iman | 4 |
| 999 | Jam | 4 |
| 999 | Klade | 5 |

And I want to achieve something like this:

| ID | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 999 | Abby | Cass | Faye | Greg | Klade |
| 999 | Betty | Dianne |  | Honey |  |
| 999 |  | Elly |  | Iman |  |
| 999 |  |  |  | Jam | ` |

I have tried joins, pivots, aggregates, but nothing seems to possibly work out (as far as I tried it.)
I even tried getting all the raw data and creating a new table but the only id I can reference them with is the ID.

Please help.
Any idea or references or resource to the right direction would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivot is one option.

```
  select *
  from (select id, name, code,
        row_number() over (partition by code order by name) rn
        from test
       )
  pivot
    (listagg(name, '') within group (order by null) val
     for code in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    );
```

which results in

```
        ID         RN 1_VAL      2_VAL      3_VAL      4_VAL      5_VAL
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       999          1 Abby       Cass       Faye       Greg       Klade
       999          2 Betty      Diane                 Honey
       999          3            Elly                  Iman
       999          4                                  Jam
```

Comment: Thanks @Littlefoot! This helped me! I appreciate it!

Comment: Hi @Littlefoot, a little follow up, please, how would I incorporate other columns in the query, like another column beside each names' column, like betty's Gender as 4th column and  Gregs' Gender as 7th column, please, I played around my current code and it messes up the order of the rows.

Comment: SELECT *
FROM (
 SELECT plan_id
  ,name
  ,readiness_code
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
   PARTITION BY plan_id
   ,readiness_code ORDER BY name
   ) rn
 FROM NAMES
 )
PIVOT(LISTAGG(name, '') WITHIN GROUP (
   ORDER BY NULL
   ) FOR readiness_code IN ('0_1 _Year' AS x_0_1_year, '1_2 _Years' AS x_1_2_years, '2_3_Years' AS x_2_3_years, 'READY_NOW' AS x_ready_now, 'NO_READINESS' AS x_no_readiness))

Comment: Well, people say that here - on Stack Overflow - you ask a question and get an answer. That's what happened here. Now your requirements have changed (new columns, new output) so - they say that you should open a **new question**, posting new sample data and desired output. But, as far as I'm concerned, if you post that by editing the original question you asked, I'll have a look. Can't promise I'll find the solution, though.

Comment: Thanks @Littlefoot, let me check what I can do as a workaround with the answer given as to not have another question asked. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, @RJ_

Answer (score 0):

The key idea is to use `row_number()`, but I prefer conditional aggregation:

```
select code,
       max(case when code = 1 then name end) as code_1,
       max(case when code = 2 then name end) as code_2,
       max(case when code = 3 then name end) as code_3,
       max(case when code = 4 then name end) as code_4,
       max(case when code = 5 then name end) as code_5
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, code order by name) as seqnum
      from t
     )
group by id, seqnum
```